# How do I install the Android NDK bundle using the command line?

Tags: android, android-ndk

The Android NDK can now be installed directly from the SDK manager instead of only as a separate download. How can I install the NDK package from the command line?

I've tried:

```
android sdk update -u -n -a
```

but no NDK package appears to be visible in the listing. It only shows up in the UI.

Answer (score 36):

In Android Studio 2.3 is `sdkmanager` tool

It is located in the `sdk` directory (i.e. ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin)

to get a list of installed and available packages goto the directory where the `sdkmanager` binary is located and type `./sdkmanager --list`

to install NDK directly use `./sdkmanager "ndk-bundle"`

(`./sdkmanager "lldb;2.3"`, `./sdkmanager "cmake;3.6.3155560"`)

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema is throwing, do you know why?

Comment: seems to be common since 2018 don't know why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402772/failed-to-install-android-sdk-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-a/46405092

Comment: JAXB was removed from the Java standards at the same time as the modules was introduced (it was moved into a module with Java9 but is entirely gone from Java11).

Comment: This seems like the right idea, but it doesn't actually work.  It does work if you don't specify a revision, but if you add a version (taken straight from the --list option), you'll get something like: "Warning: Failed to find package ndk-bundle;18.1.5063045"

Answer (score 8):

1. Download zip file of required version of ndk from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html#beta-downloads). E.g. for linux:

   wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r13b-linux-x86_64.zip
2. Extract zip to some folder, e.g. `c:/android/android-ndk-r13b/`
3. Add/update the path to that folder in the `local.properties` file of your application.

   ndk.dir=c:\android\android-ndk-r13b

Comment: I specifically want to download it as an SDK component.

Comment: Sorry to inform, but it's not served by android.bat as sdk component as far as I see. Try to raise a suggestion to Google about it. And even the new sdkmanager.bat is not providing anything ndk related

Comment: Updated url to download NDK: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r14b-darwin-x86_64.zip