# Failed to install android-sdk: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema"

Tags: java, android, java-9

When installing the android sdk tools the following error is emitted:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Debug output:

```
$ java --version
java 9
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
$ brew cask install android-sdk
==> Caveats
We will install android-sdk-tools, platform-tools, and build-tools for you.
You can control android sdk packages via the sdkmanager command.
You may want to add to your profile:
  'export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk'

This operation may take up to 10 minutes depending on your internet connection.
Please, be patient.

==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-darwin-3859397.zip
Already downloaded: /Users/tomasnovella/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/android-sdk--3859397,26.0.1.zip
==> Verifying checksum for Cask android-sdk
==> Installing Cask android-sdk
==> Exception in thread "main"
==> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
==>     at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
==>     at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
==>     at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
==>     at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:117)
==>     at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:93)
==> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
==>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
==>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
==>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
==>     ... 5 more
Error: Command failed to execute!

==> Failed command:
/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools build-tools;26.0.1

==> Standard Output of failed command:


==> Standard Error of failed command:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:117)
```

Comment: Actually this question asks a legit problem with installing the android sdk when having java9

Comment: I has this problem, and I copy/pasted the first line of my error message into google, and this question was the first hit that came up. Not only that, one of the answers below solved it. This should totally not be closed: no matter what the rules of questions are, this question demonstrably fulfills the whole purpose of the site.

Comment: Delete anything older than Java 8 from `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

Comment: The problem occurs with Java 8 and Java 11 on Ubuntu 18.04 using packages `openjdk-8-jdk` and `openjdk-11-jdk`. Does anyone know what to install for `javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema`, or how to avoid `javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema` in the NDK?

Comment: it is not about the Java version guys. it's about the command-line tools. I passed this error Java 16 after I install command-line tools. Also you can find the correct answer page two in this question.
`Android Studio -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Android SDK Command-line Tools -> Install`

Comment: @ssss, thanks. that's the actual cause "command-line tools".

Answer (score 187, accepted):

I had a similar problem this morning (trying to build for Android using Unity3D). I ended up uninstalling JDK9 and installing [Java SE Development Kit 8u144](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

1. `brew cask uninstall java` # uninstall java9
2. `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions`
3. `brew cask install java8` # install java8
4. `touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg` # without this file, error will occur on next step
5. `brew install --cask android-sdk`

Comment: thx... brew cask install java is installing java9 now and that will cause this error when installing android-sdk. Had to install java8 in order to proceed

Comment: 1. brew case uninstall java  # uninstall java9
2. brew tap caskroom/versions
3. brew cask install java8  # install java8
4. touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg  # without this file, error will occur on next step
5. brew cask install android-sdk

Comment: Got the error on windows 10, tried this, still doesn't work. Any tips?

Comment: @Vedvart1 On Windows 10 x64, uninstalling JDK 9.x and installing JDK 8u161 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Great - this worked for me building a Flutter app in Android Studio. Thanks!

Comment: On Windows 10, I installed JDK 8u162 and set the `JAVA_HOME` this JDK to correct the issue. No need to uninstall JDK 9.x

Comment: Just read `Unity requires the 64-bit version JDK 8 (1.8).` https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html

Comment: I prefer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52788062/5405601) posted below because it doesn't need to downgrade java. Just set correctly `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: This stopped working, brew cask install java8 does not work.

Comment: the correct command seems to be now `brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/java8`

Comment: `brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8` seems to work

Comment: I have tried doing all of these steps as mentioned above, but I still get the same error message. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: @AnubhavDinkar, looks like a problem with later versions after version 8. You'd have to install any java after v-8 and then install v-8(`jdk8`)

Comment: Another solution is to use the JDK included in your Android studio. In my case it's:
 `JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home" ./sdkmanager --licenses`

Comment: I had to use ```brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8``` instead of ```brew cask install java8```

Comment: You can `brew install jenv` to switch between java versions, much like nvm or virtualenv and other languages

Comment: I'd strongly suggest adding [SDKMan](https://sdkman.io/) to the solutions. This does a better job of managing multiple versions of Java

Comment: `brew install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8` worked for me.

Comment: This answer is obsolete, see below for up-to-date answers, e.g. this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64389804/218294

Comment: For macOS Big Sur users, use: `brew install --cask ...`

Comment: it is not about the Java version guys. it's about the `command-line tools`. I passed this error Java 16 after I install command-line tools. Also you can find the correct answer page two in this question. `Android Studio -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Android SDK Command-line Tools -> Install`

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted solution any longer, but the one from EdYuTo!

Answer (score 587):

Just had this error, solved by downloading the `Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)` on Android Studio, under `Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools` and re-running `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

> **NOTE:** For Android Studio *Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1*, find these setting under `File` > `Settings` and, in the left panel, `Languages & Frameworks` > `Android SDK` and finally select the `SDK Tools`.

[image: Android SDK path on Android Studio]

[image: Command-line Tools]

Finally, add the new tools to your PATH, in your `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` or similar, before the obsolete tools:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
```

Comment: Tried the above solutions but as 2021 in a freshly installed env none worked. This is was the right answer for me.

Comment: Ubuntu 21 woked flawlessly

Comment: Getting following error when performing `flutter doctor --android-licenses` after installing the `Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)`: `Error: Could not find or load main class Sight\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\\..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Sight\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\\//`

Comment: Work for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS..Thanks @Sam_Watkins

Comment: This should be marked correct answer. Downgrading Java is not the correct approach, that is highly regressive!

Comment: Worked on macOS 10.15.7 and Java 11.0.4

Comment: this worked for me on M1 chip macOS big Sur 11.5.1

Comment: Solved my issue with Flutter setup not being able to accept licenses on M1 Big Sur

Comment: Now, there is no option called "Preferences" on Android studio. "System Settings" are now available in File

Comment: Preferences is now under File -> Settings... (Ctrl + Alt + S)

Comment: This answer helped me fixing it (on Windows 10). But I used "sdkmanager --licenses" in the folder "...\cmdline-tools\latest\bin" to accept all missing licenses.

Comment: On a Mac, Click on top left on 'Android Studio', then Preferences, or `Cmd ,`

Comment: I'm still getting errors on mac
You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=31'. 
java 17.0.2

Any idea why?

Comment: on my macOS in addition to what's explained I had also to move `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin` in `PATH` to after `$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin` since there are failing sdkmanager/avdmanager binaries in there

Comment: still facing this issue in the env. Cordova11 android10

Comment: The main point is use tools from `$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin` instead of `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin`.

Comment: This did not work for me on linux. I needed to navigate into the tools/bin folder and run sdkmanager from there.

Comment: As for android studio electric eel, the android sdk is available through system settings and not preferences

Comment: NOTE that this error may also suddenly pop-up after you, for some reason, changed your adb key! (~/.android/adbkey and ~/.android/adbkey.pub) In case you have access to your old adb key + pub file (like I had) you may just re-instate the old key and the error will go away.

Answer (score 132):

- I also had this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 5 more
```

- then instead  of uninstalling the latest java environment, (in my case it is java 13)
- and installation of `java 8`,
- I have done the following steps
- `open the android studio > go to configure > select sdk manager > go to sdk tools > make a tick on android sdk command line tools >apply > and wait for installation`

[image]

[image]
[image]

- restart the command line tool
  [image]
- enter the command `flutter doctor`
- enter the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
- and accept all the licenses by typing `y`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Curious how you figured this out.

Comment: Finally, a solution that works. I cannot thank you enough for posting this!

Comment: I'll have to remember this one.  Getting the license tool to work was crazy for JAVA_HOME and this little tick mark and 5 minutes  let me build my project.  Nice screenshots too.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10! Thank you!

Comment: @Pradyot In the event you're running into build issues where your environment might be the culprit, it's a good idea to always run `flutter doctor -v`

Answer (score 98):

To solve this error, you can downgrade your Java version.

Or exports the following option on your terminal:

**Linux/MAC:**

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

**Windows**:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee
```

If this does not work try to exports the `java.xml.bind` instead.

**Linux:**

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.xml.bind'
```

**Windows**:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.xml.bind
```

And to save it permanently you can exports the `JAVA_OPTS` in your profile file on Linux (`.zshrc`, `.bashrc` and etc.) or add it as an environment variable permanently on Windows.

---

**ps.** This doesn't work for Java 11/11+, which doesn't have Java EE modules. For this option is a good idea, downgrade your Java version or wait for a Flutter [update](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Changelog).

Ref: [JDK 11: End of the road for Java EE modules](https://jaxenter.com/jdk-11-java-ee-modules-140674.html)

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04 w/ OpenJDK 10.0.2

Comment: Worked for me on macOS Mojave (10.14.2) with Java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17.

Comment: Created a new error for me on macOS Mojave (10.14.2):
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found

Comment: @Randy your Java version?

Comment: java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS

Comment: I also tried 1.8.0_191, but am still getting:
Error: Could not find or load main class java.se.ee

Comment: This option is not needed for the Java 8 and doesn't work for the Java 11, which doesn't have Java EE modules.

Comment: Not working, 
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found

Comment: In window syntax you must not use apostrophes, simply: set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee   
But it not works out of the box: java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found

Comment: @JavaRunner, yes, like we can see at the end of the answer

Comment: @MGM YES! I can't believe i copied the apostrophes... :D 
Thank you!

Comment: Apparently, java.se.ee does not exist anymore

Answer (score 68):

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee
```

This fixed the problem on Windows for me.

[Source 1](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3139#issuecomment-363950869), [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47150411/270197)

Comment: Also used this on ubuntu 16.04 (using `export` not `set`) and it resolved the problem.

Comment: Genius. Thanks so much. Thought I was gonna have to change my JVM

Comment: Worked like a charm on Windows 10 with Java 10

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to have been removed entirely in Java 11.

Comment: Worked doing `export JAVA_OPTS = '-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'` on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thanks a lot for this , worked on jdk-14.0.2 , windows 10

Answer (score 61):

**Update 2019-10:**

As [stated in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67495440#comment13), Google has been working on a new **Android SDK Command-line Tools** release that runs on current JVMs (9, 10, 11+) and does not depend on deprecated JAXB EE modules!

You can download and use the new **Android SDK Command-line Tools** inside Android Studio or by manually downloading them from the Google servers:

- [SDK Tools for Linux](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip)
- [SDK Tools for Mac OS](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-mac-6200805_latest.zip)
- [SDK Tools for Windows](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-win-6200805_latest.zip)

For the latest versions check the URLs inside the [repository.xml](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml).

If you manually unpack the command line tools, take care of placing them in a subfolder inside your `$ANDROID_HOME` (e.g. `$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/...`).

**Update 2021-03:**

The latest stable command-line tools are available at [Googles Downloads-Website](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools).  These tools are newer than those linked above.

Comment: When using Java 9+, this should be the answer from now on!

Comment: You should probably use the new command-line tools regardless of Java 8 oder 9+ ;)

Comment: i am still having the same error, can you tell me where exactly do i need to place it

Comment: @RohanDevaki `c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat`

Comment: @Ashish it works for all OS. I don't know what "did not work" means, but you may check out this issue if you manually unpacked the executables: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143335476

Comment: you are right. I was putting it in wrong directory. It should be in $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest ... I was using latest stable command-line tool mentioned at the bootom.

Comment: This worked for me on Fedora 34 in May 2021, after a fresh install of Android Studio. Had to navigate to $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin and accept licenses using the sdkmanager script here.

Comment: Now (6 Juni 2021), android studio no longer use java8 but java11. This should be the correct answer, rather downgrade the version of java.

Answer (score 36):

If you're on Mac OS, and you don't want to change your Java version (I don't), you can temporarily change the version in your shell:

First run

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Then pick a major version if you have it installed, otherwise install it first:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

Now you can run sdkmanager.

Comment: `$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V` gives `bash: /usr/libexec/java_home: No such file or directory`.  `apt-file search /usr/libexec/java_home` gives exactly nothing.

Comment: Do you have $JAVA_HOME set correctly? Run: ```echo "export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`" >> ~/.bashrc``` (or profile if you use profile) - reload: ```. ~/.bashrc```

Comment: There is no `/usr/libexec` either.  Are you on MacOS? (I am on Ubuntu/Linux and Ubuntu/Windows)

Comment: I am using mac. where's your Java_home?

Answer (score 28):

When using Linux, an easy option is installation of `JDK version 8` then selecting it as the default using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: should probably mention this is linux only

Answer (score 24):

On Mac/Linux use the following command:

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

Works for both JDK 9 and 10, **without** patching any script (sdkmanager, avdmanager).

For Java 11 see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51644855/798165

Comment: thanks! it solves the problem when you have installed jdk 9

Answer (score 21):

You need to add the following to your Profile (Works on MacOS):

> ```
> export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
> ```

No need to patch anything.

Answer (score 21):

While building the flutter application an error occurred saying android sdk licenses not accepted. So, while accepting the license this error occurred.

Reason for this error in my case was I haven't installed sdkmanager command line tools which is required to accept the license.

So, to install command line tools easiest way is:

1. Open android studio.
2. Open SDK Manager (refer image below):
   [image]

3. Select SDK tools inside it in bar.
4. Tick the option Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)
5. Apply it.
6. Run flutter doctor -android-licenses if using flutter or you can continue with the process where the error occurred.

Comment: What if we want to run `avdmanager` from commandline?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky . I only use physical device but here is what I have found from the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Answer (score 15):

I found two answers that worked for me, without having to uninstall JDK 10 (or 9), which I need for `create-react-app`.  Both JDK 9 and 10 are incompatible with android-sdk !

---

[Siu Ching Pong -Asuka Kenji-](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47150411/5411817) suggests modifying the `sdkmanager` script, replacing this line:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME"'
```

with:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME" -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

Note that this mod will be overwritten when updating sdkmanager.
Check out his post, and the one he links to, for more details.
This solution was also one of the solutions mentioned in this [github issues thread](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3139).

---

[German's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630166/5411817) indicates the source of the conflict, and presents fix that will not not be overwritten by updates.
He suggests renaming `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/Info.plist` as a means of obscuring it from the script that looks for the highest version of Java that resides on your system.  In this way, JDK 8 is returned as the default.
Referring to JDK 10 explicitly, or by setting it to `$JAVA_HOME`, you can use JDK 10 , instead of the default, whenever needed.
Details are in his post.

Comment: Worked perfectly, best solution IMHO as it doesn't force you to downgrade java

Comment: Somehow, after experimenting a lot with ao. Android Studio, this issue disappeared and the new error was `Could not find or load main class java.se.ee` - reverting the DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS fixed this and the previous issue went away..

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work now. The result is:

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found

Comment: Upvoted https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630166/5411817 for having the correct solution for keeping jdk-11 and jdk1.8 installed without downgrading

Answer (score 13):

Strangely Java9 is not compatible with android-sdk

```
$ avdmanager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 5 more
```

Combined all commands into one for easy reference:

```
$ sudo rm -fr /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9*.jdk/
$ sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
$ sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane

$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
Matching Java Virtual Machines (0):
Default Java Virtual Machines (0):
No Java runtime present, try --request to install

$ brew tap caskroom/versions
$ brew cask install java8
$ touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg
$ brew cask install android-sdk
$ echo 'export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
$ avdmanager

Usage:
      avdmanager [global options] [action] [action options]
      Global options:
  -s --silent     : Silent mode, shows errors only.
  -v --verbose    : Verbose mode, shows errors, warnings and all messages.
     --clear-cache: Clear the SDK Manager repository manifest cache.
  -h --help       : Help on a specific command.

Valid actions are composed of a verb and an optional direct object:
-   list              : Lists existing targets or virtual devices.
-   list avd          : Lists existing Android Virtual Devices.
-   list target       : Lists existing targets.
-   list device       : Lists existing devices.
- create avd          : Creates a new Android Virtual Device.
-   move avd          : Moves or renames an Android Virtual Device.
- delete avd          : Deletes an Android Virtual Device.
```

Comment: Error: caskroom/versions was moved. Tap homebrew/cask-versions instead.

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same problem. Though I am a little bit backdated developer (Still using windows to develop :P)

To solve this issue **on windows** :

STEP 1: Install jdk 8 if it wasn't installed (jdk 9 or 11 doesn't work but you may have them installed for using in other dev uses).

Very simple using Chocolatey:

> choco install jdk8

**(If installed using Chocolatey, skip steps 2 and 3)**

STEP 2: Go to the Environment variables settings and set JAVA_HOME TO jdk 8's installation directory.

[image: JAVA_HOME]

STEP 3: Go to path variable and add bin directory of jdk 8 and move it to top.

[image: Path_varriable]

STEP 4: Close any open terminal sessions and restart a new session

OPTIONAL STEP 5: Depending on your objective in the terminal run (may need to add sdkmanager to path or just navigate to the directory):

> sdkmanager --update

That's all! :O Enjoy fluttering! :D

Comment: This along with the top answer worked for me on windows 10!

Comment: THANKSSSSSSSSSSSSSS

Comment: Works! I just want to add, that if you are using VS code, you have to restart the program after this change

Comment: This worked for me on windows 10. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into same issue when running:

```
$ /Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.0.3"_
```

I solved it as

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home    

$ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

jdk-11.0.1.jdk      
jdk1.8.0_202.jdk
```

**Change Java to use 1.8**

```
$ export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home'
```

Then the same command runs fine

```
$ /Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.0.3"
```

Comment: This is the best case. If you already export JAVA_OPTS. Please remove it first before you do the steps from this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Since Java 11 has removed JavaEE you'll need to download some jars and add to the classpath:

JAXB:
https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/

JAF:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-135046.html

Then edit sdkmanager.bat so that **set CLASSPATH=...** ends with **;%CLASSPATH%**

Set CLASSPATH to include JAXB and JAF:

```
set CLASSPATH=jaxb-core.jar;jaxb-impl.jar;jaxb-api.jar;activation.jar
```

Then sdkmanager.bat will work.

Comment: It works, but I get this warning:
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/F:/android_sdk/java/jaxb-ri/lib/jaxb-impl.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)

Comment: Ya, looks like Java is starting to warn against bad programming practice of using reflection to bypass class security, which JAXB uses (Oracle breaking their own rules) ;)

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I need both JDK 8 (trying to use the AVD and SDK manager in Qt under ubuntu) and 11 for different tools. Removing version 11 is not an option.

The 'JAVA_OPTS' solutions did not do anything. I don't really like the export JAVA_HOME, as it might force you do launch whatever tool calls these utils from the same shell (like Qt), or force you to make this permanent, which is not convenient.

So for me the solution is quite simple. Add something like this in the second line of ~/Android/tools/bin/sdkmanager and  ~/Android/tools/bin/avdmanager:

`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"`

(or whatever the path is to your rev 8 jdk).

With this, these command line tools work in a stand alone mode, they work also when called by other tools such as Qt, and jdk 11 is still the system default for others. No need to mix libs etc...

The only downside is that any update to these command line tools will erase these modifications, which you will have to put back in.

Comment: best option if you don't want to mess with PATH variables.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I have Java 14 and need Java 8.

I'm in a Arch Linux and has installed `jdk8-openjdk jre8-openjdk` https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/java8-openjdk/

For Debian users https://wiki.debian.org/Java, or Fedora https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/installing-java/.

Install Java 8 (or desired version, in this case `jdk8-openjdk jre8-openjdk`) using your package manager before doing the following steps.

---

## 1. Figuring out where is my Java:

```
# which java
/usr/bin/java
```

## 2. Checking java files:

I can see all java files here are links to `/usr/lib/jvm/default[something]`. This means that the `java` command is linked to some specific version of `java` executable.

```
# ls -l /usr/bin/java*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 May 16 06:30 /usr/bin/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 May 16 06:30 /usr/bin/javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 May 16 06:30 /usr/bin/javadoc -> /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/javadoc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 May 16 06:30 /usr/bin/javah -> /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/javah
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 May 16 06:30 /usr/bin/javap -> /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/javap
```

## 3. Checking the `default` and `default-runtime`

Here I could see the default version was linked to 14 (unique installed version).

```
# cd /usr/lib/jvm
# ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Aug  8 20:44 default -> java-14-openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Aug  8 20:44 default-runtime -> java-14-openjdk
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 19 22:38 java-14-openjdk
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Aug  8 20:42 java-8-openjdk
```

## 4. Switching the default version

First, remove the existing `default` and `default-runtime` which linked to java-14 version.

```
# rm default default-runtime
```

Then, create new links to the desired version (in this case, java-8).

```
# ln -s java-8-openjdk default
# ln -s java-8-openjdk default-runtime
```

---

The strategy is to make links to the desired version of software (java8 in this case) using `ln -s` above. Then, this links are linked to the binaries inside the java bin directory (**without changing the `$PATH` environment variable!**)

---

Or you might be wanted to change the Java version using `archlinux-java` command instead with more safely approach: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java

Answer (score 5):

As of the latest version of the Android command-line tools (2.1 as of this writing), it is no longer necessary to patch sdkmanager nor to downgrade to an ancient version of Java.

Simply update your SDK packages and switch your command-line tools to the `latest` release, which will track new versions as they come:

```
sdkmanager --update
sdkmanager 'cmdline-tools;latest'
sdkmanager --uninstall 'cmdline-tools;1.0'
```

You may need to provide the full path to `sdkmanager` if it's not on your `PATH`, and you may need to adjust your `PATH` afterwards if it was referring to the `1.0` tools explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR; Try setting JAVA_HOME worked fine for me on OSX

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

To install the JDKs 8 ( LTS ) from AdoptOpenJDK:

```
# brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk

brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

Comment: I tried a lot of things, this was the missing link for me on OSX Big Sur

Answer (score 4):

For **Windows** users looking for solution

<kbd>Option 1</kbd>  Install the cmdline-tools from within the **Android Studio SDK manager**

[image]

---

<kbd>Option 2</kbd>  Download from this link https://developer.android.com/studio#cmdline-tools

Then follow this tutorial below on how to set it up
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvi03sOBKWQ

---

Next copy the path to where the cmdline-tools was installed towards the ***bin*** folder

> *Using **Android Studio SDK Manager***
> The cmdline-tools is installed under the Android SDK Location
> Example:
> **C:\Users\%*username*%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**\cmdline-tools\latest\bin

---

Then paste the path in to the Environment Variable Path

> <kbd>Control Panel</kbd>> Set the ***View By*** to <kbd>Large Icons</kbd>><kbd>System</kbd>>Under '***Related Settings***' on the right side choose <kbd>Advanced System Settings</kbd>><kbd>Environment Variables</kbd>

From here you add the path under System variables
[image]

Make sure that the cmdline-tools path is above the tools path (*highlighted in the picture in red box*) if they exist.

> Select the Path><kbd>Edit</kbd>>Select the cmdline-tools path (*highlighted in blue*) ><kbd>Move Up</kbd>

Comment: I think the issue here is that it conflicts with the existing sdk tools files so by moving the cmdline-tools path up solves which path files to access first and i hope others can replicate in  linux environment ^_^ "avdmanager works" no need to downgrade

Comment: For MacOS user, option 1 is the simplest solution. 

Comment: Hi @Nati i did what you said but now when i am running i am getting this error "Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Detected 'avdmanager' command at C:\Users\aksha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin but no 'tools\bin' directory found near.
Try reinstall Android SDK or update your PATH to include valid path to SDK\tools\bin directory.
"

Answer (score 3):

This question has numerous answers, and they're all different due to users installing different toolchains and using different Java versions.

The recommended way of using Android development toolchain, or at least the one that I suggest to use, is to follow what's stated in Android Studio documentation:

> You should always keep your Build Tools component updated by downloading the latest version using the Android SDK Manager.

Android studio allows you to easily manage installed SDKs & build tools, yes, it requires some space on your hard drive, but it will save you some time. Once you get familiar with how it works, then you can think of installing command-line tools only.

If there's no particular reason of using older Java version, use the latest (stable) version, you will have interesting new features, and also the compiled application will benefit from all the new optimizations.

### Fresh install

1. Delete your local `Android` folder, usually in the home directory
2. [Download Android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)
3. Once installed, open `Settings`, Search `Android SDK` and open it
4. In `SDK Platforms` select the target Android version for your app
5. In `SDK Tools` tab, select `Android SDK Build-Tools`, `Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)`, `Android Emulator`, `Android SDK Platform-Tools`
6. Before pressing OK, check that `Android SDK Location` path is correct for you
7. Press OK and let Android Studio download & install everything

(Optional) if you need to use the installed binaries from command line, be sure to add their folder into your PATH variable. If you use Android studio, it's should not be required though.

I've got Java 14 installed on my machine, anyway you can use the jre shipped with Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I didn't have the required sdk version installed on my machine.

So make sure that you have installed the sdk version which is given in the error.

Here you can navigate check & install via Android Studio.

[image: Android Stuido SDK Manager]

Answer (score 2):

For Linux users (I'm using a Debian Distro, Kali)
Here's how I resolved mine.

If you don't already have jdk-8, you want to get it at oracle's site

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

I got the jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz

Step 1 - Installing Java
Move and unpack it at a suitable location like so

```
$ mv jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz /suitablelocation/
$ tar -xzvf /suitablelocation/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

You should get an unzipped folder like jdk1.8.0_191
You can delete the tarball afterwards to conserve space

Step 2 - Setting up alternatives to the default java location

```
$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /suitablelocation/jdk1.8.0_191/bin/java 1
$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /suitablelocation/jdk1.8.0_191/bin/javac 1
```

Step 3 - Selecting your alternatives as default

```
$ update-alternatives --set java /suitablelocation/jdk1.8.0_191/bin/java
$ update-alternatives --set javac /suitablelocation/jdk1.8.0_191/bin/javac
```

Step 4 - Confirming default java version

```
$ java -version
```

Notes

1. In the original article here: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?41-Installing-Java-on-Kali-Linux,
   the default plugin for mozilla was also set. I assume we don't really need the plugins as we're
   simply trying to develop for android.
2. As in @spassvogel's answer, you should also place a @repositories.cfg file in your ~/.android directory
   as this is needed to update the tools repo lists
3. Moving some things around may require root authority. Use sudo wisely.
4. For sdkmanager usage, see official guide: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager

Answer (score 2):

This question has multiple answers depending on the underlying issue. There are also multiple answers that indirectly fix the actual problem.

The core issues are:

1. Android SDK tools have issues with the latest *Oracle* JDK. You can use the latest *Open* JDK. (The latest OpenJDK comes with Android Studio.)
2. You don't have the latest Android SDK command line tools installed.
3. You have the latest Android SDK command line tools installed, but you are using E:\Android\Sdk\tools\bin instead of E:\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin.

Here are systematic steps to identify and fix any of the above issues that you may have.

1. Point environment variables to your OpenJDK installation in Android Studio. Depending on your installation that is found here: E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre. You have to go through all the necessary variables like PATH, JAVA_HOME, JAVA_BIN etc and make sure that they all point to your OpenJDK.

Note: You don't have to uninstall/reinstall JDKs. That simply probably fixes your variables above as a side effect.

2. Check that your environment variables are correct (Windows: echo %JAVA_HOME%, echo %PATH%, where javac, etc.)
3. Go to Android Studio. In Settings, navigate to "Appearances & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK." Install "Android SDK Command Line Tools."
4. In the shell, go to E:\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin and run sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"

Additional troubleshooting tips:
I had Android environment variables messed up as well. Run 'flutter doctor -v' and the output will help you troubleshoot additional environment configuration issues.

Answer (score 1):

For windows machine uninstall the JDK if its more than 1.8.172. 
Install JDK 1.8.172

I was facing the same issue in windows 10 with java 10. I uninstalled the java 10 and installed java8 its working fine for me now :)

Answer (score 1):

Run `java -version` and `javac -version` commands in a command line to make sure that they come from the same JDK (eg: version 1.8.0_181)

If not, you have to modify `PATH` variable so that it only points to a single JDK. If you are not sure how to, just uninstall all other Java instances except for Java 8 (Add/Remove Programs in Windows). As for today, both Unity and Android recommends that you use JDK 8.

With Java 8, it is not necessary to export `java.se.ee` module as shown in some of the other answers. You may also remove any `JAVA_OPTS` or other [environment variables](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) that you have set.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your java version.Whatever system or ide.

Make sure java version is not higher than 8

In my case.I change the ide java verion.This solves my issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had recently solved this problem by uninstalling the higher version of JDK and installing JDK 8. After installing the JDK you need to give the path. Then you need to open command prompt in "C:\Users\Milan Adhikari\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools" and run "sdkmanager --update" which will update your sdk and then you need to run "flutter doctor --android-licenses" in cmd and accept all the licenses.
Now your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use below command

```
   $ wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip
   $ unzip \platform-tools-latest-linux.zip
   $ sudo cp platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
   $ sudo cp platform-tools/fastboot /usr/bin/fastboot
```

Now run adb version to verify it’s been updated.

Answer (score 1):

No need to uninstall your other java version(s) that's already installed on your machine. Whenever required, you can conveniently use the utility 'update-alternatives' to choose the Java runtime that you wish to activate. It will automagically update the required symbolic links.

You just need to run the below command and select the version of your choice. That's all!

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 1):

As @steven pointed out, install Java 8 (here a link for Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 and 20.04/20.10 https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-java-8-on-ubuntu/) and then set it as the default Java version with this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

When your Android stuio/jre uses a differ version of java, you will receive this error. to solve it, just set Android studio/jre to your JAVA_HOME. and uninstall your own java.

Answer (score 0):

For me i install java version 8 and just select the java version in "JDK location":
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For my circumstance, I'm using sdkman to manage multiple java versions. I set default java version to 13. Install version 8 and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and had installed `openjdk-8-jdk` as suggested. Checking `javac -version` resulted in the correct version, but `java -version` showed version 11.

The solution was to use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and select version 8 from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

My Java version is 15.0.1 . For the OS Mac.

and this is how i fixed the issue.

1. downloaded zip: jaf-1_1_1.zip from: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jaf/1.1.1/jaf-1_1_1.zip?AuthParam=1609860571_68ca6f30491c76e81970a3849504fb6a
2. downloaded the zip: jaxb-ri-2.3.1.zip from: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jaf/1.1.1/jaf-1_1_1.zip?AuthParam=1609860571_68ca6f30491c76e81970a3849504fb6a
3. unziped into a folder: ~/jars/ . exported classpath as follows

```
export  
 CLASSPATH=~/jars/FastInfoset.jar:~/jars/activation.jar:~/jars/codemodel.jar:~/jars/dtd-parser.jar:~/jars/istack-commons-runtime.jar:~/jars/istack-commons-tools.jar:~/jars/jaf-1.1.1:~/jars/jaf-1_1_1.zip:~/jars/javax.activation-api.jar:~/jars/jaxb-api.jar:~/jars/jaxb-jxc.jar:~/jars/jaxb-ri:~/jars/jaxb-ri-2.3.1.zip:~/jars/jaxb-runtime.jar:~/jars/jaxb-xjc.jar:~/jars/relaxng-datatype.jar:~/jars/rngom.jar:~/jars/stax-ex.jar:~/jars/txw2.jar:~/jars/xsom.jar
```

1. next edit the file: `cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager` change the CLASSPATH to the below

`CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$APP...`

save the file and run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

Updated my current Android SDK and everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error running "flutter doctor --android-licenses" In Windows 10. I solved it creating these two environment variables

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

ANDROID_SDK_HOME
C:\Users\youruser\.android
```

Refresh environment variables or reboot and then run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, however, another way to fix this error is by connecting an Android phone to your laptop (i.e. run the app on a physical device). Ensure the USB debug mode is enabled.
[image]

Comment: yep, apparently my PC wasn't detecting my phone and I had to add it again