# Failed to run sdkmanager --list with Java 9

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools, java-9, android-sdk-manager

I downloaded and installed:

- JDK (`jdk-9.0.1_osx-x64_bin.dmg`) from Oracle [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
- Android SDK (`sdk-tools-darwin-3859397.zip`) from Google [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).

After configuring the `PATH` variable, I tried running `sdkmanager`, which replaced the `android` command for managing SDK components. However, it failed as shown here:

```
$ sdkmanager --list
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:117)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 5 more
```

Here is the Java version:

```
$ java -version
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it without going back to Java 8?

## Related Questions

- [Failed to install android-sdk: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46402772/142239)

  - This post asked a similar question. However, the post is closed and the only answer suggests going back to Java 8.

## WARNING

Please note that I already mentioned above that going back to **Java 8** or running it side-by-side is **NOT** what I wanted.

Comment: Just wondering: what is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Trying new features in Java 9, but at the same time developing Android apps, and just want one JDK in the system.

Comment: The linked answer is not Android SDK specific. It did not point out which script to edit, and where to edit. Please note that not everybody knows shell script, and it helps to solve the problem quickly even for people who know. Do you want to read though a script not written by you to solve a simple configuration problem, while a working solution is out there already tested by someone?

Comment: On that note, I've voted to reopen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402772/failed-to-install-android-sdk even as the comments pointed out.

Comment: Please don't delete this until https://stackoverflow.com/q/46402772/142239 is re-opened, and I copy my answer there. I don't have a backup of my StackOverflow posts. Thanks!

Comment: I was with java latest installed, downgrade for java8 in variables env and work fine

Comment: none of the solutions worked for me. had to go back to java 8

Comment: It's as if google develops new complications faster then they could appear themselves for developers. Upgrade a component by .1 versions and welcome to a 3 day domino effect of brand new issues.

Answer (score 169):

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/142239), I successfully solved the problem.

We are going to apply a fix in `sdkmanager`. It is a shell script. It is located at `$android_sdk/tools/bin`, where `$android_sdk` is where you unzipped the Android SDK.

1. Open `sdkmanager` in your favorite editor.
2. Locate the line which sets the `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS`variable. In my copy, it is at line 31:

   ```
   DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME"'
   ```
3. Append the following options to the variable: `-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee`. **Please pay attention to the quotes.** In my copy, the line becomes:

   ```
   DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME" -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
   ```
4. Save the file and quit the editor.
5. Run the command again.

Here is the result:

```
$ sdkmanager --list
Installed packages:
  Path    | Version | Description              | Location
  ------- | ------- | -------                  | ------- 
  tools   | 26.0.1  | Android SDK Tools 26.0.1 | tools/  

Available Packages:
  Path                              | Version      | Description                      
  -------                           | -------      | -------                          
  add-ons;addon-g..._apis-google-15 | 3            | Google APIs                      
  add-ons;addon-g..._apis-google-16 | 4            | Google APIs                      
  add-ons;addon-g..._apis-google-17 | 4            | Google APIs                      
  add-ons;addon-g..._apis-google-18 | 4            | Google APIs                      
  add-ons;addon-g..._apis-google-19 | 20           | Google APIs                      
  add-ons;addon-g..._apis-google-21 | 1            | Google APIs                      
  add-ons;addon-g..._apis-google-22 | 1            | Google APIs                      
  add-ons;addon-g..._apis-google-23 | 1            | Google APIs                      
  add-ons;addon-g..._apis-google-24 | 1            | Google APIs
...
```

Hola! It works!

## -- Edit: 2017-11-07 --

Please note that you may need to apply the fix above again after running `sdkmanager --update`, since the `sdkmanager` shell script may be overridden if the `tools` package is updated.

## Related Answers

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/142239

  - @andy-guibert pointed out the necessary options to make this work. He also briefly what those mysterious options mean.

Comment: As noted in the JDK 9 Migration Guide `--add-modules java.se.ee` should be a considered a temporary workaround. The proposal to drop the java.xml.bind module from Java SE and the JDK is in draft form here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189188

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. As the software in concern is the Android SDK, which is developed by Google, I am not responsible or able to do what you suggested. Please send a bug report to Google. Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply export the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable, `export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'`, instead of patching the SDK source files?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! That's a good idea! By applying this, there is no need for the user to patch the script again after an upgrade. However, the setting (usually made in shell startup scripts) affects not just sdkmanager, but also other applications as well. And this may not be what the user wants to do.

Comment: FWIW, I downloaded and installed both the JDK and Android SDK Tools today on Windows 10, and had to set the line to be `set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=%~dp0.." -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee` to get the `com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli` class to run correctly

Comment: Sir, did you know that you've just saved someone's life? I could have stroke or something. I did what you said, you've just solved a problem for me, three excruciating, heart wrenching days of trying to get it to work!!!!!!! THANKS A LOT

Comment: @Mahmoud I'm glad to hear that! Please keep on your good work to write us some fantastic Android apps!

Comment: Hi All, Now I got a new problem. XMlSchema error is resolved but now ......Any solution please.* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler

Comment: What a burning shame to have releases that are so unfinished and untested. It just feels like some developers dont realize there are many companies that need good job with Android and **problems like this cost thousands of dollars**.

Comment: Though I settled on this solution (easier for me to keep track of), an [alternative "solution" is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630166/5411817).  A long term fix would be wonderful.

Comment: I agree with @Rafa, setting the `JAVA_OPTS` is easiest. Note that on Windows you need to put it without double quotes: `set JAVA_OPTS=--add-modules java.se.ee`

Comment: I have no tools folder

Comment: when having java 11 in the system, the solution that @SherylHohman proposed must be combined with this one, java 11 must be "hidden" from the list to make this work

Comment: This  `-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee` or `--add-modules java.xml.bind do not work with Java 11 on Mac OS. 

How can I fix it without installing another version of Java?

Comment: No way to get sdkmanager (at least of version 26.1.1) to run with Java 11 IMO. You need to downgrade or have a separate installation of Java 8..10 configured in "sdkmanager" source with "JAVA_HOME" override

Comment: I still get another error: ```Error: Could not find or load main class '-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=D:\Android_SDK-26.0.1\tools\bin\\..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: '-Dcom/android/sdklib/toolsdir=D:\Android_SDK-26/0/1\tools\bin\\//```

Comment: if you are using java 11 or later
Try changing this like in sdkmanager.bat
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% --add-modules java.xml.bind %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

Comment: In ubuntu 18.04 with Java --version 11, this does not work and instead throws the error ``` Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found
``` after rerunning the command

Comment: Hola == Voila??

Comment: As of Java 11 or later, this solution is not applicable anymore as the Java EE APIs are no longer included with the JDK packages. If downgrading Java is an option, Java 1.8 will work fine.

Comment: It won't work after Java 11 or later

Answer (score 48):

The accepted answer is outdated as of February 2019. [Here's an answer](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16025#issuecomment-468009198) that will work until `sdkmanager` migrates to a newer version of Java. But by then, you won't have this problem anymore.

> [OpenJDK 10 was superseeded by OpenJDK 11](https://jdk.java.net/10/), which doesn't implement `java.se.ee` *at all*. This means that the hack of adding `--add-modules java.se.ee` doesn't do anything anymore. It also means that OpenJDK 10 will be automatically removed from your system and replaced with OpenJDK 11 the next time you update, if your updates are configured properly.
>
> Modify `sdkmanager` to use Java 8 by setting `JAVA_HOME` *inside* `sdkmanager` to a Java 8 installation. It's, by default, at `~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager`.
>
> ```sh
> # Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and SDKMANAGER_OPTS to pass JVM options $
> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
> DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME" -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions'
> ```
>
> ```
> @rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and SDKMANAGER_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
> set JAVA_HOME="C:\ProgramData\scoop\apps\android-studio\current\jre"
> set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=%~dp0\.."
> ```
>
> This way, you can keep using a sane and maintained version of Java on your system while simultaneously using `sdkmanager`.
>
> ```sh
> # Java
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
> ```
>
> And now I've got some [pipelines](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10495562/53575275-3504db80-3b3f-11e9-810a-ca49ef9373c4.png) to repair.

Comment: This answer helped me, as I temporary set JAVA_HOME top point to Java installation from Android Studio: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

Comment: `set JAVA_HOME="...\android-studio\current\jre"` helps me on Windows 10 while all other answers didn't

Comment: `set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre"` worked fro me on Windows 10. Find out your Android Studio Path. I have set Java 11 on my original JAVA_HOME

Comment: This won’t work: Java 8 no longer exists in Debian stable (1½ years old) and newer.

Comment: @NatoBoram I use IntelliJ IDEA without the bundled binary JRE. I use the distribution’s JRE because that’s the one with security support, and our machine policy requires us to keep our software secure.

Comment: In 2021, this answer was the one that worked perfectly.

Comment: I suggest running `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)` vs the hardcoded path

Comment: March 2022, this answer still works +1

Comment: On Mac, I had to first download JDK 1.8 https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html and then set the variable `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: Jul 2023 - this is what worked

Answer (score 39):

You can set sdkmanager options with SDKMANAGER_OPTS.

Example:

```
export SDKMANAGER_OPTS="--add-modules java.se.ee"
sdkmanager --list
```

Comment: Please note on Windows you should omit the quotes: `set SDKMANAGER_OPTS=--add-modules java.se.ee`

Comment: java.se.ee doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: This answer is outdated, someone fix this please

Answer (score 34):

Install the Command-line Tools in the SDK Manager via Android Studio.

[image: Installing Command-line Tools]

Then run the version of SDK Manager **from the `cmdline-tools` directory, as opposed to the `tools` directory**.

```
$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --version # GOOD!
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager                --version # BAD! (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)
```

Comment: This one should be correct answer

Comment: This has worked for me on macOS, run `$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --list` to get the list. Not sure if the update is actually necessary, would be cool if somebody could try with the latest Android Studio installation without updating first?

Comment: Does this mean `$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin` should be added to the `$PATH` instead of `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin`?

Answer (score 29):

When having java 11 in the system, the solutions provided are not valid.

This `-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee or`--add-modules java.xml.bind do not work with Java 11 on Mac OS.

For that reason you have to downgrade java version to version 8 from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

## List Java versions installed

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

## Java 11

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)
```

## Java 1.8

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

Then go to

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
```

and

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

Comment: I did this and still get the error : etc... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.. I am using Java 12.0.1

Comment: @jamesemanon maybe do a restart to apply the changes. I don't have any clue.

Comment: `bash: /usr/libexec/java_home: file not found` at my install.

Answer (score 20):

**Update 2019-10:**

As [stated in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67495440#comment13), Google has been working on a new SDK tools release that runs on current JVMs (9+)!

You can download and use the new **Android SDK Command-line Tools** inside Android Studio or by manually downloading them from the Google servers:

- [SDK Tools for Linux](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip)
- [SDK Tools for Mac OS](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-mac-6200805_latest.zip)
- [SDK Tools for Windows](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-win-6200805_latest.zip)

For the latest versions check the URLs inside the [repository.xml](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml).

If you manually unpack the command line tools, take care of placing them in a subfolder inside your `$ANDROID_HOME` (e.g. `$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/...`).

**Update 2021-03:**

The latest stable command-line tools are also available at [Googles Downloads-Website](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools)

Comment: Command line tools 2.1 (latest) also fail like this, with Java 11.

Comment: @mirabilos there has to be an other issue with your setup. Android Studio Arctic Fox (current Canary) is shipped with JDK11 embedded. It runs fine. And we use Java 11 on our CI machines and never had any issues.

Comment: This helped me as of 1/2022 on Windows 10, Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 4. Wen to: Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> checked Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest). After the download, opened Windows Explorer in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat. Ran "cmd" in the address bar to open command prompt there, then ran `sdkmanager.bat --licenses`. It downloaded a list of licenses, then typed "y" a lot to accept them all.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

I just add "Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)" and this solved my issue.

Originally from here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56778#issuecomment-742639036

Answer (score 14):

For Windows, if nothing works then try this:

- Open `sdkmanager.bat` with Notepad.
- Locate the following line:

  `%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%`
- Add `--add-modules java.xml.bind`

The modified line should look like this:

`%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% --add-modules java.xml.bind %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%`

Comment: Worked for me on windows 10.

Comment: java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found

Answer (score 10):

As we read in the previous comments this error is occurring because the current SDK version is incompatible with the newest Java versions: 9 and 10.

So, to solve it, you can downgrade your java version to Java 8, or as a workaround, you can export the following option on your terminal:

**Linux:**

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

**Windows**:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

If this does not work try to exports the `java.xml.bind` instead.

**Linux:**

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.xml.bind'
```

**Windows**:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.xml.bind'
```

This will solve this error for the `sdkmanager`

And to make it saved permanently you can export the JAVA_OPTS in your profile file on Linux (`.zshrc`, `.bashrc` and etc.) or add it as an environment variable permanently on Windows.

---

**ps.** This doesn't work for Java 11/11+, which doesn't have Java EE modules. For this option is a good idea, downgrade your Java version or wait for a Flutter [update](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Changelog).

Ref: [JDK 11: End of the road for Java EE modules](https://jaxenter.com/jdk-11-java-ee-modules-140674.html)

Comment: When I try this, im getting another error:  

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee' not found

Comment: @SherinBinu which Java version are you using?

Comment: try to use `--add-modules java.xml.bind` instead of `--add-modules java.se.ee`

Comment: The `--add-modules` approach will no longer in Java 11+
I have found this working answer on another post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076422/getting-android-sdkmanager-to-run-with-java-11

Comment: @lbenedetto, yeah, we can read this at the end of the answer

Comment: Yes, but their provided work around of downgrading Java is bad. I linked a post that explains how to download and install the required missing components.

Answer (score 10):

As some people have mentioned before, this very well could be a simpler problem having to do with one java installation taking precedence over the other.

In my case it was java 8 being overshadowed by a default newer java.

I installed java 8:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Then I updated the installed java to be the new default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Whereby I selected java 8's id number.

After doing these (pretty simple) steps, I could just run sdkmanager without error.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This won’t work: Java 8 no longer exists in Debian stable (1½ years old) and newer.

Comment: I interpreted the question (at the time that he wrote it, not the time of an apparent edit?) that he would be okay installing it alongside. Still, I like my answer being here because I myself was searching for how to do this and the above worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

The Android Tools are still incompatible with JDK 9 or 10. You need to install JDK 8 or, if you need multiple Java versions make sure that the system-wide Java home points to a JDK 8.

More details here: [How to configure Unity 2017.4 to target Android and avoid build failures on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630165/how-to-configure-unity-2017-4-to-target-android-and-avoid-build-failures-on-osx/49630166#49630166)

Answer (score 5):

I had a tough time figuring out this solution just adding the working sdkmanager.bat

```
@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
@rem ##########################################################################
@rem
@rem  sdkmanager startup script for Windows
@rem
@rem ##########################################################################

@rem Set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal

set DIRNAME=%~dp0
if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%..

@rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and SDKMANAGER_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=%~dp0\.."


@rem Find java.exe
if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome

set JAVA_EXE=java.exe
%JAVA_EXE% -version >NUL 2>&1
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:findJavaFromJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe

if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:init
@rem Get command-line arguments, handling Windows variants

if not "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto win9xME_args

:win9xME_args
@rem Slurp the command line arguments.
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
set _SKIP=2

:win9xME_args_slurp
if "x%~1" == "x" goto execute

set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*

:execute
@rem Setup the command line

set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\sdklib-25.3.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\layoutlib-api-25.3.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\dvlib-25.3.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\repository-25.3.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\gson-2.2.4.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\httpclient-4.1.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\httpmime-4.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\common-25.3.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\kxml2-2.3.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\annotations-25.3.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\annotations-12.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jimfs-1.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\httpcore-4.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\commons-codec-1.4.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\guava-18.0.jar

@rem Execute sdkmanager
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS%  -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee  %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

:end
@rem End local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto mainEnd

:fail
rem Set variable SDKMANAGER_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of
rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!
if  not "" == "%SDKMANAGER_EXIT_CONSOLE%" exit 1
exit /b 1

:mainEnd
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal

:omega
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not viable option since this will stop working when new version of SDK comes out since this code snippet contains hard-coded versions: `set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\sdklib-25.3.1.jar`

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve the issue by using an edited sdkmanager.bat file by forcing to use the Java embedded inside the Android Studio Itself, which i presume uses the OpenJDK 8. Here is the edited sdkmanager I Used :

```
@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
@rem ##########################################################################
@rem
@rem  sdkmanager startup script for Windows
@rem
@rem ##########################################################################

@rem Set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal

set DIRNAME=%~dp0
if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%..

@rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and SDKMANAGER_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=%~dp0\.."

@rem find Java from Android Studio
@rem Find java.exe
if defined ANDROID_STUDIO_JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromAndroidStudioJavaHome

set JAVA_EXE=java.exe
%JAVA_EXE% -version >NUL 2>&1
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto init

goto findJavaNormally

:findJavaFromAndroidStudioJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%ANDROID_STUDIO_JAVA_HOME:"=%
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe

if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto init

goto findJavaNormally




@rem java from java home
@rem Find java.exe
:findJavaNormally
if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome

set JAVA_EXE=java.exe
%JAVA_EXE% -version >NUL 2>&1
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto init

goto javaError

:findJavaFromJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe

if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto init

goto javaDirectoryError



:javaError
echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:javaDirectoryError
echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail


:init
@rem Get command-line arguments, handling Windows variants

if not "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto win9xME_args

:win9xME_args
@rem Slurp the command line arguments.
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
set _SKIP=2

:win9xME_args_slurp
if "x%~1" == "x" goto execute

set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*

:execute
@rem Setup the command line

set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\dvlib-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jimfs-1.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\repository-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\layoutlib-api-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\gson-2.3.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\httpcore-4.2.5.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\commons-compress-1.12.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\annotations-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\error_prone_annotations-2.0.18.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\httpclient-4.2.6.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\commons-codec-1.6.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\common-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\kxml2-2.3.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\httpmime-4.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\annotations-12.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\sdklib-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\guava-22.0.jar

@rem Execute sdkmanager
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

:end
@rem End local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto mainEnd

:fail
rem Set variable SDKMANAGER_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of
rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!
if  not "" == "%SDKMANAGER_EXIT_CONSOLE%" exit 1
exit /b 1

:mainEnd
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal

:omega
```

Here i used an environmental variable ANDROID_STUDIO_JAVA_HOME which actually points to the JRE embedded in the android studio eg: ../android_studio/jre

This also has a fallback to JAVA_HOME if ANDROID_STUDIO_JAVA_HOME is not set.

Answer (score 3):

Short addition to the above for openJDK 11 with android sdk tools before upgrading to the latest version.

The above solutions didn't work for me

```
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=%~dp0\.."
```

To get this working I have installed the jaxb-ri (reference implementation) from the maven repo.

The information was given https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2 and links to the https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-ri/2.3.2/jaxb-ri-2.3.2.zip
This download includes a standalone runtime implementation in the mod-Folder.

I copied the mod-Folder to $android_sdk\tools\lib\ and added the following to classpath variable:

;%APP_HOME%\lib\mod\jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\mod\jakarta.activation-api.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\mod\jaxb-runtime.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\mod\istack-commons-runtime.jar;

So finally it looks like:

```
set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\dvlib-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jimfs-1.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\repository-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\layoutlib-api-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\gson-2.3.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\httpcore-4.2.5.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\commons-compress-1.12.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\annotations-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\error_prone_annotations-2.0.18.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\httpclient-4.2.6.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\commons-codec-1.6.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\common-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\kxml2-2.3.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\httpmime-4.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\annotations-12.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\sdklib-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\guava-22.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\mod\jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\mod\jakarta.activation-api.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\mod\jaxb-runtime.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\mod\istack-commons-runtime.jar;
```

Maybe I missed a lib due to some minor errors showing up. But 
sdkmanager.bat --update or --list is running now.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did in Ubuntu 18.04 (Any Linux will do):

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk

$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac    1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2

$ export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64)
```

Comment: This won’t work: Java 8 no longer exists in Debian stable (1½ years old) and newer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer to make this work for Java 11 and above since the entire JAXB APIs were removed.

Download [Jakarta XML Binding](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri), specifically [this zip](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-ri/2.3.3/jaxb-ri-2.3.3.zip) file. You need only the 3 files within mod folder i.e. jakarta.activation.jar, jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar and jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar and you can toss the rest off.

Move these files to APP_HOME/lib folder. I created a sub folder **jaxb** inside for this. So, on my macOS system this was:
$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/jaxb

Now open sdkmanager using your favorite text editor and under CLASSPATH= add the following at th beginning:

```
$APP_HOME/lib/jaxb/jakarta.activation.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jaxb/jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jaxb/jaxb-impl.jar
```

So it ended up looking like:

```
CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/lib/jaxb/jakarta.activation.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jaxb/jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jaxb/jaxb-impl.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/dvlib-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jimfs-1.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/repository-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/layoutlib-api-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/gson-2.3.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/commons-compress-1.12.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/annotations-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/error_prone_annotations-2.0.18.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/httpclient-4.2.6.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/common-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/kxml2-2.3.0.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/httpmime-4.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/annotations-12.0.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/sdklib-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/guava-22.0.jar
```

And that's pretty much it, should solve the issue.

I did these steps because `flutter doctor --android-licenses` was giving me issues. And this fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

(WINDOWS)

If you have installed Android Studio already go to `File` >> `Project Structure...` >> SDK  Location.

Go to that location + `\cmdline-tools\latest\bin`
Copy the Path into `Environment Variables`

than it is OK to use the command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

The only working solution for me is to use the java shipped with the Android studio.

set the JAVA_HOME to  `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`

in `.bashrc`

`set JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"`

If you are using `fish` shel, put this in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

`set -gx JAVA_HOME /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`

(This is for mac, but I am sure it should work with linux and windows by setting the correct path)

Comment: This might interfere with other application trying to use the Original/Non-OpenJDK version of Java from Oracle. Eventhough OpenJDK is more than capable, some might need the other one as well.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently if you use "commandlinetools" version greater than 3.6.0 you may use JDK11+ to install Android SDK components.

They are available here: https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools

Official issue tracker saying it is fixed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122210344#comment11

Answer (score 1):

As explained above by Saifur Rahman Mohsin, the problem is that `sdmanager` relies on the availability of J2EE functionality which no longer ships with JRE/JDK >= 11, so this can be worked around by using the [JAXB classes](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/) which implement the same functionality.

However, you may prefer not (or not be able to) modify the `sdkmanager` script (e.g. because it is installed by some other process that you do not control). If you are running a Posix/Unix system (like GNU/Linux or BSD, maybe macOS) you may still have a chance.

At least with the `sdkmanager` shipped with `sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip` (maybe also with later versions), if you set `$JAVA_HOME`, it tries to look for `$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java` for IBM's AIX SDK compatibility. So you can exploit that compatibility check to trick `sdkmanager` into using a wrapper script that inserts the necessary classes into the class path when calling the real `java` program.

For example, in Debian with OpenJDK 11 already installed (package `openjdk-11-jre` or `openjdk-11-jdk`) you can do this (as root):

```
# cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64  # use your Java home here
# mkdir -p jre/sh
# cd jre/sh
# touch java
# chmod a+rx java
```

Then edit the just-created `java` script and write this Bash code into it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cp="$JAVA_EXTRA_CLASSPATH" java="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
test "$cp" || exec "$java" "$@"

args=()
for arg in "$@"; do
    if [[ "$setcp" ]]; then
        cp="$arg:$cp" setcp=
    elif [[ "$arg" =~ ^-(cp|-?classpath)$ ]]; then
        setcp=y
    else
        args+=("$arg")
    fi
done
exec "$java" -cp "$cp" "${args[@]}"
```

To make `sdkmanager` use the wrapper script and inject the JAXB classes into the class path, first install the relevant JAXB package in your system (`libjaxb-java` in Debian), and use `sdmanager` like this:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"  # for Debian's OpenJDK 11
$ export JAVA_EXTRA_CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java/jaxb-impl.jar"  # for Debian's `libjaxb-java` package
$ (now run sdkmanager or other processes running it as usual)
```

Please note that `$JAVA_EXTRA_CLASSPATH` has classpath syntax, so you can enter a colon-separated list of items.

I noticed that this trick also applies to the Gradle wrapper and maybe others, but they may be safe if `$JAVA_EXTRA_CLASSPATH` is not set.

Answer (score 0):

https://adoptopenjdk.net currently supports all distributions of JDK from version 8 onwards.
For example https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html#x64_win

Here's an example of how I was able to use JDK version 8 with sdkmanager and much more: https://travis-ci.com/mmcc007/screenshots/builds/109365628

For JDK 9 (and I think 10, and possibly 11, but not 12 and beyond), the following should work to get sdkmanager working:

```
export SDKMANAGER_OPTS="--add-modules java.se.ee"
sdkmanager --list
```

Comment: Any idea of how to fix this for SDK 12?

Comment: @Richie Did you solve this, I too have Java 12 and running into this issue and nothing that is posted here is helping.

Comment: As I recall, I think you have to download the jar file that contains java.se.ee and add it to the path (or something similar). AFAIK Oracle unbundled J2EE-related  jars from the JDK for 12 and beyond. Did not test this with sdkmanager.

Comment: @jamesemanon I did not manage to solve it. Try the above suggestion

Answer (score 0):

**JDK 13.0.1, Android SDK 29 , Windows 10**

Basically i tried everything, but the most effective and only 1 solution that worked for me was to downgrade to jdk 1.8. I dont why, it is early 2020 and have to downgrade to 1 year old jdk version against latest flutter version. Maybe problem is in windows version, cause jdk 13.0.1 worked for me on macOS 10.15.2. Hope this solution works.

Download Link (JDK 1.8.0):
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Java 8 was released in march 2014. So it is a bit more than 1 year old...

Comment: yeah..but Oracle policy has changed since Java 8.....it is not free for organisation anymore. So, everyone are forced to use Java8

Comment: The problem is that newer java runtimes (9+) do not have javax libraries, you are supposed to ship them with your application. So software written expecting to run on java 8 and before do not ship these libraries, and thus won't work on 9+. The reason, as you guessed, is to make the standard JDK fully open source (these libraries are not GPL), so I would say that the license terms improved.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install jaxb har files and include in the classpath. this works in java 11 to 12 latest.

To those who are looking for the fix i made some gist in github hope this help. and the links are provided also.

https://gist.github.com/Try-Parser/b7106d941cc9b1c9e7b4c7443a7c3540

Answer (score 0):

Define home directories of different JDK versions in your .bashrc or .zshrc:

```
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
export JAVA_14_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v14)
```

First of all use JDK version 8. Put this line the top of `sdkmanager` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME
```

Switch back to JDK version 14. Put this line the bottom of `sdkmanager` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_14_HOME
```

Comment: This won’t work: Java 8 no longer exists in Debian stable (1½ years old) and newer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flutter,
Run this command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Answer (score 0):

For users on mac, I solved an issue similar to this by modifying my zshrc file and adding the following (although your java_home might be configured differently) :

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/YOURUSER/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/YOURUSER/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:%ANDROID_HOME%\tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/YOURUSER/Library/Android/sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a M1 chipset and the only solution was to install the JDK 8 from azul zuru and then change my JAVA_HOME to 1.8 and works!

Answer (score -1):

Another solution possible to this error is check your Java version, maybe you can solve it downloading this jdk  [oracle-jdk-8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), this was my mistake :P

Answer (score -1):

I download Java 8 SDK

1. unistall java sdk previuse
2. close android studio
3. install java 8
4. run-> `cmd-> flutter doctor --install -licenses`
   and after

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.388], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category
display  and finish
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to `{SDK_FOLDER}/lib/_/` (underscore folder). Copy all the files from the `_` folder to its parent folder `/lib`.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same error while trying to build apk using unity engine.
The main problem for this error was using "jdk11" instead of "jdk8".
I have done the below steps to successfully compile my apk

1. Delete all the folders present in your java folder. C:\Program Files\Java
2. Uninstall any existing java applications in your system[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpf8D.png)

3 Download java8 from oracle https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html
4. Install it.
By following the above i solved the problem