# Android Gradle dependency compile doesn't work with Java 9

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, java-9, gradlew

Friends,

I was trying to run gradle command (mentioned below) to resolve dependencies

```
gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

I am using JDK9 and and using gradle 4.4 but when run above mentioned command getting an error.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   >     javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 20s

Please help me on this.

Comment: Did you run with `--stacktrace` to see more output? Is it Gradle or your app that uses JAXB and have you added the standalone download of JAXB as a dependency?

Comment: which version of android gradle plugin?

Comment: gradle 4.4 version

Comment: @DipendraSharma I was referring to the gradle-build-tools, I have no problem to run your gradlew cli with Java 9 and Gradle 4.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an Android SDK problem with Java 9: [Failed to run sdkmanager --list (Android SDK) with Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150410/failed-to-run-sdkmanager-list-android-sdk-with-java-9)