# sdkmanger is not working

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-manager

I had download sdkmanager on laptop. the sdkmanager resides in `~/Android/tools/bin` When I try to launch it via terminal it give me this output:-

```
./sdkmanager --list
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:117)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 5 more
```

I am using Oracle Java 9.0.1

Comment: Are you sure Android SDK supports Java 9?

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150410/failed-to-run-sdkmanager-list-android-sdk-with-java-9)

Comment: @cricket_007 i don't know . I new java. Android sdk is dependency for cordova and that why I installed it. I just picked the latest version of java.

Comment: @SantiagoSalem YES!!! thanks it worked !!!!