# How to fix 'No suitable Java found' error in android.bat (android sdk/tools)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set up the android-sdk but the sdkmanager won't show up.

because of this Error massage i cheked my *JAVA_HOME* variable, witch is pointing correctly to the jdk instalation:

if i run

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

in cmd i get

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1
```

this is the output of android.bat

```
C:\Android\sdk\tools>android.bat

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
JDK folder.

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html


C:\Android\sdk\tools>
```

Comment: AFAIR the Android SDK requires Java 7 or 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to run sdkmanager --list (Android SDK) with Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150410/failed-to-run-sdkmanager-list-android-sdk-with-java-9)

Answer (score 2):

If java downgrade didn't work for you try this

After long struggle I was able to figure out the issue, Not sure if this is a valid fix but that did fix it.

In the latest Android studio version 3.4 in
 **C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\find_java.bat** on **line 44**
it looks like this

```
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%~dps0\find_java%arch_ext%.exe" -s') do set java_exe=%a%
```

if you give

echo of %~dps0\find_java%arch_ext%.exe

this line it is supposed to print the path of  the find_java32.exe or find_java64.exe based on your machine architecture but it adds // slashes in the path just before final finde_javax.exe which was causing an issue.

so I just modified it to look like below and it worked.

**"  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%~dps0%find_java%arch_ext%.exe" -s') do set java_exe=%a%  "**

Do let me know if there is a better solution or if this works for you

Answer (score 1):

@Saravinfotech's answer didn't work for me but it pointed me at the right place. The double `\` still called `find_java64.exe` for me, but running that:

```
$ .\find_java64.exe -e
Failed to find Java 1.6 (or newer) on your system. [2] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Even though `java.exe` was on my path and `JAVA_HOME` was set to my oraclejdk\current folder. Not worth debugging though.

I just patched the script with these additions:

```
set java_exe=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe

set javaw_exe=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe
```

and the script stopped complaining.

---

Looking back, there might be bigger problems going on. `monkeyrunner.bat` is calling java.exe with arg`-Djava.ext.dirs` instead of `-classpath` which isn't supported as of JDK9 (?), and even working around that, I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundError`. A recent release of Java 14 seems very incompatible.

**Installing JDK8 was the fix.**

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution which **DON'T NEED ONE TO DOWNGRADE TO JAVA 8** so, there is option for JRE to run VM for "uiautomatorviewer".

One needs to install Android Studio and add the below location to "path" System Variable

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin
```

I have jdk-11.0.6 and "uiautomatorviewer" is working fine.

Comment: I installed jdk16 and even i was getting the same error. but adding the jre path and moving this path to top helped me fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is installing Java 8 and changing all java paths to the Java directory (`C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8`) and Setting `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Other answers did not work for me.