# Android SDK [console tools] only shows "Usage" help info when I try to execute any command

Tags: android-sdk-manager

I have Java SE development kit 12.0.1.

I am trying to get Android SDK to work with IntelliJ IDEA. I've downloaded SDK manager command line tools (Revision 26.1.1 (September 2017)) from Google's website.

At first, sdkmanager threw exception when I tried to launch it, but I have fixed this by editing sdkmanager.bat (as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150410/failed-to-run-sdkmanager-list-android-sdk-with-java-9)). Now it doesn't crush, but when I try to execute a command (such as `sdkmanager --update`) it only shows the help page titled "usage". The execution of the command doesn't happen. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Android SDK doesn't support Java/JDK 12, so I installed JDK 8 and it worked.