# Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to detect adb version

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-emulator, logcat

I am currently having this problem when I am opening a project:

[image: Click To View Image]

The errors showing in Event Log :

> Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc0000409, adb output: adb.exe F 11-11 09:55:06 17768   944 fdevent_poll.cpp:64] failed to create fdevent interrupt socketpair: Invalid argument

The errors showing in event Log:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:93: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

Comment: I think the `adb.exe` file is missing from `<android_path>/sdk/platform-tools` directory. Can you check it once? Are you using any (Free) antivirus programs like Avast or AVG? If YES, disable it while testing your Android app code.

Comment: Yes, the platform- tools is there.

Comment: To solve the problem I just uninstalled the whole application and all of its components and reinstalled it. But the problem is still there

Comment: I said `adb.exe` file not `platform-tools` folder. Check for the EXE file in that folder.

Comment: yes the file adb.exe is there

Comment: Did you try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49345049/5180017)?

Comment: let me try them all

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I tried every possible solution I could find online. Uninstalled Android studio COMPLETELY. I only downloaded platform-tools from Android studio site, and when I run any adb commands, I get the first error.

Comment: @SHOONYA did you get the solution for this?

Comment: i also tried every possibilities but still having the same issues. also i was not yet installed any antivirus too.
once i running adb command i got this message.
`adb.exe F 11-25 08:25:14  4384  6404 fdevent_poll.cpp:64] failed to create fdevent interrupt socketpair: Invalid argument`

Comment: @VipiNNegi I have added the answer to the problem, check it out

Comment: @Dev.Barai :  I have added the answer to the problem, check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got 2 possible solutions for this problem:

> (1st) : Download Revo Uninstaller and uninstall Android Studio from it. Revo is a powerful tool which removes all the files of the selected software including program data cache files and and all remaining settings and repositories.
>   After that reinstall Android Studio and select "do not import settings" during the installation.

`Revo Installer Download Link :: (https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/)`

If it doesn't work the only remaining solution is ::

> (2nd) : Go to Settings / Update and Security / Recovery /   And reset
>   your pc. Select the option keep my files and reset it. Don't worry
>   about your other hard disk data it will only reset all the programs in
>   your C drive and will also save all the files of documents, downloads,
>   videos and images.

(I tried the second option first and it worked for me)

> The problem occurred in the first place because antiviruses tend to
>   delete temp files and android studio saves its emulator files in temp
>   folder. To solve it just go to your antivirus settings and search for
>   "add exclusion" option and add these 4 folders there:

```
(instead of rajhr open the folder with your user name)

1 .  C:\Users\rajhr\.android   
2 .  C:\Users\rajhr\.AndroidStudio3.5 

3 .  C:\Users\rajhr\AppData\Local\Android

4 .  C:\Users\rajhr\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator
```

And also add them to windows defender Settings : 
1. Open windows defender 
2. Go to firewall and network protection
3. Select allow app through firewall and add the 4 folders there.

Hope the answer helps you btw this is my first StackOverflow answer.

Answer (score 7):

This problem is not with your adb.exe or android studio.
And you don't need to reinstall Studio or reset windows.

Actually your Windows stopping adb.exe to start socket server because somehow some antivirus or third party app disturbed your network settings.

**The solution is:**

you need to reset the network settings.

1) Run CMD promt as administrator.

2) Type command "netsh winsock reset"

3) restart pc if needed

Now if you open studio there would be no adbhostserver error.

Comment: I had tried the solution provided by you early but it didn't worked so I had no option left rather than reset my windows and reinstall Studio

Comment: no problem,but this worked for me thats why i posted this so that someone can get benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

go to 'netsh' in your pc (C:\Windows\System32)

[click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W924v.png)

run it as administrator ,a command window will open , then type 'winsock reset', now restart your PC....and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Change Autoplay settings in Windows for your Device.