# Environment is not configured correctly after restart?

Tags: mobile, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Working on a Nativescript Angular project from a Windows computer, I managed to get to a point where I would get errors from gradle (since I'm working behind a proxy that does not like gradle) however after a restart I can no longer run the project since even running "ns doctor" will tell me there is an issue with the environment that it is not set up correctly.

[image]

Tried restarting the entire process and setup on a colleagues laptop and we've hit the exact same issue after a restart.

Nothing seems to have changed in the Environmental Variables so I can't tell what's going on or what is the issue

Comment: The solution here might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795573/unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-server-unable-to-detect-adb/59339056#59339056