# Can't execute apkanalyzer

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to run `apkanalyzer` from Android SDK tools from command line. However, it won't start and prints the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The tools directory property is not set, please make sure you are executing apkanalyzer. Got /home/user/Programs/android-sdk-linux/tools
    at com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli.getAaptInvokerFromSdk(ApkAnalyzerCli.java:266)
    at com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli.main(ApkAnalyzerCli.java:123)
```

My cmdline is:

```
~/Programs/android-sdk-linux$ tools/bin/apkanalyzer apk summary ~/projects/mservice.apk
```

`ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is set.

Here is my installation (sdkmanager --list):

```
Installed packages:=====================] 100% Computing updates...             
  Path                 | Version | Description                    | Location             
  -------              | ------- | -------                        | -------              
  build-tools;28.0.3   | 28.0.3  | Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 | build-tools/28.0.3/  
  build-tools;29.0.2   | 29.0.2  | Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 | build-tools/29.0.2/  
  platform-tools       | 29.0.6  | Android SDK Platform-Tools     | platform-tools/      
  platforms;android-28 | 6       | Android SDK Platform 28        | platforms/android-28/
  platforms;android-29 | 4       | Android SDK Platform 29        | platforms/android-29/
  tools                | 1.0.0   | Android SDK Tools 1            | tools/
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Which command are you using to open your APK?

Comment: @MatPag I get the same error with any command. Or do you mean what exactly my cmdline is?

Comment: yes, I mean what is exactly your command

Comment: @MatPag updated in description

Comment: `sdkmanager --list` is giving you all the installable packages, not the one installed on your machine.
Open Android Studio and in the SDK Tools tab be sure to have download `Android SDK Tools 26.1.1`

Comment: This problem also happen to me. I can't run apkanalyzer. Error msg: "The tools directory property is not set". Seems it can't detect "build-tools\30.0.3" directory.

Answer (score 2):

`apkanalyzer` expects to live in a different folder than it is actually in. This is the same error as with `sdkmanager`, also part of `cmdline-tools`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65262340/cmdline-tools-could-not-determine-sdk-root): The solution is to move `/path/to/cmdline-tools` to `/path/to/cmdline-tools/latest`.

I found this by googling for `The tools directory property is not set` > [https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/.../Main.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/87a88c4f030dc8d60911ccb236f45d854e89877e/tools/sdkmanager/app/src/com/android/sdkmanager/Main.java) > `com.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir` > run `sdkmanager` > `Error: Could not determine SDK root.` > [Failed to run sdkmanager --list with Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150410/failed-to-run-sdkmanager-list-with-java-9).

Answer (score 1):

your tools version is version is very old.

It should be atleast greater than 26.0

Use

```
sdkmanager --install tools
```