# Flutter unable to find android-sdk

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am on Ubuntu 21.04, I download the Command Line tools from here: https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads .

I am following this guide to setup Flutter without Android Studio: https://dev.to/ejgamer21/install-flutter-without-android-studio-58bi

I extracted it in my home directory. I also did:

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools"
sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"
sdkmanger "platforms;android-29"
```

My directory looks something like :

```
android-sdk/
           build-tools/
           cmdline-tools/
           emulator/
           licenses/
           patcher/
           platforms/
           platform-tools/
           tools/
```

Also I move contents from `cmdline-tools` to `cmdline-tools/tools` following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65262939/13725696.

I did `flutter config --android-sdk /home/[username]/android-sdk/`, but still I get this on running `flutter doctor`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Linux, locale en_IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
      more details.
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at
    google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

**edit**: I just noticed this:

```
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
```

I did `flutter doctor --add-licenses`, but I receive this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add environment variables like this:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/[username]/android-sdk/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

to `~/.bash_profile` in the home directory and restart.