# ReactNative can't locate Android SDK

Tags: android, react-native

I've followed the installation instructions for ReactNative on the official site but can't get my project to build and install on any device. The issue seems to be that ReactNative can't seem to locate my Android SDK.

If I open the Android specific part of the project in Android Studio I can start the app, so the SDK is properly installed. Maybe related is also that I'm working on a Flutter app simultaneously and Flutter has no problems locating the Android SDK.

Running `nix react-native doctor` gives me the following:

```
Common
 ✓ Node.js
 ✓ yarn
 ✓ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode

Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 29.0.2
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

iOS
 ✓ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
 ✓ CocoaPods - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ✓ ios-deploy - Required for installing your app on a physical device with the CLI

Errors:   1
Warnings: 0

Attempting to fix 1 issue...

Android
 ✖ Android SDK
   Read more about how to download Android SDK at https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started
```

However trying to "fix" the issue just takes me to the getting started page, and as I mentioned before I've done the installation exactly as described. I even tried removing everything related to Android from my computer and reinstalling everything from scratch.

Runnit `nix react-native info` gives me the following:

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.4
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 1.97 GB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.16.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.9.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.5, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223
    Xcode: 11.5/11E608c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 14.0.1 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0
    react-native: 0.62.2 => 0.62.2
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Which just further "proves" that ReactNative can't find the Android SDK.

**What I've tried so far:**

Adding a `local.properties` with the content:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk
```

(And yes the folder exists and is correct, it's the same one set in Android Studio)

Updating the `.zshrc` with:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

And in that sdk-folder (in platforms) I have `android-28`, `android-29` and `android-30`.
I've also (of course) looked at a number of posts here from people with the same issue, but one of these two fixes almost always seems to solve the issue, however it doesn't work for me. What else is there to test?

UPDATE:
I can also add that when running `npx react-native run-android` and tget the error: `Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.`. But this problem should also be solved with the `properties.local`, which doesn't work for me.

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, did you found any salutation, I am having the same error, please help.

Answer (score 35):

I figured out that installing the "Android SDK Command-line Tools" plugin in Android Studio will allow doctor to recognize a newer android sdk instance!

But it's incompatible with react-native, we need the **29.0.2** one so be sure to check "Show package details" and select the correct version before downloading it.

[image: Android Studio settings]

My `npx react-native doctor` output after that:

```sh
michel@michel-ubuntu:~/development/projects/Project$ rn doctor
Common
 ✓ Node.js
 ✓ npm

Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

Errors:   0
Warnings: 0
Common
 ✓ Node.js
 ✓ npm

Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

Errors:   0
Warnings: 0
```

Answer (score 8):

Steps to fix this on (mac m1):

- Follow Steps from https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
- ensure you have added JAVA_HOME in ~/.zshrc

  ```
  export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home
  ```
- As described in environment-setup you need to install `Android 13 (Tiramisu)` only.
- make sure the following items are checked:

  - Android SDK Platform 33
  - (for Apple M1 Silicon) Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image
- Then configure Env Vars:

  ```
  export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
  ```
- Make sure you install SDK Build tools version 33 by checking show packages checkbox and
- SDK Command line tools version 33.

  ```
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/10.0/bin
  ```

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/10.0/bin` this worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Also, check JVM version referenced by `JAVA_HOME`. Reason: `npx react-native doctor` uses [envinfo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envinfo) to gather available SDKs, which in turn calls `ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --list`, which can throw exceptions if too old JVM is used.

In my case, switching to Java 17 helped.

Comment: You nailed here! I followed the official documentation to install Java Azul Zulu and it doesn't run the sdkmanager properly. After switching to Java 19, it started finding the SDK

Comment: Installing `cmdline-tools/latest` did the trick for me !

Comment: Removed java 11 and installing java 17 worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Open ur android folder with Android Studio, Android Studio will try to install the required SDK for you.

Answer (score 2):

***KEY POINTS: Shall the command "sdkmanager" run correctly, will the command "react-native doctor" run correctly.***

Firstly, remove $ANDROID_HOME/tools, $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin from the PATH. The sdkmanager in there is old, and requires oracle jdk 8. While in contrast the react native requires jdk >= 11.

Secondly, add $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/10.0/bin to the PATH.（You can replace 10.0 with your own version）

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
# export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
# export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/10.0/bin
```

Then the command "sdkmanager" will run correctly.
And the command "react-native doctor" will run correctly too.

Inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68382384/7994724

Comment: Thanks for this! Regarding replace 10.0, I only had "latest", I guess that will be more future proof (or not)

Comment: in my case, `sdkmaganer` is working but `npx react-native doctor`  is not!

Answer (score 2):

Even though you have followed all the mentioned steps in the documentation,
installed SDK tools and SDK platforms, if you are not able to run the Android app, the only issue is you don't have permission to run ./gradlew

So, in order to provide permission; run

```
cd android
chmod +x gradlew

./gradlew clean
```

This will provide the execution permissions.

Then you can build your Android application using

```
npm run android
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers in stackoverflow and github issues. But the below trick worked for me.
In my case I configured the **PATH** variable in this way so that react-native doctor finds the correct tools.

```html
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platforms:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I resolved this erros when set version Java of the gradle to use jdk11 and not use android studio version jdk.

Comment: Me too: `Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0`

Answer (score 0):

Replacing JDK to version 19 works for me.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Install android command line tools from android studio SDK manager (SDK tools tab). then add <YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_PATH>\cmdline-tools\latest\bin to PATH environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio;

More Actions > SDK Manager;

SDK Tools tab;

Select Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest);

Hit Apply and let it install the package;

Try re-running the npx react-native doctor command to see if this fixes your problem

Answer (score -1):

this steps worked for me.

1. open your system environment variable>advance>enveronment variables.
2. delete every all paths related to sdk. including android_home and android_home_root.
   now restart your system. go back to the environment variable and click on path>edit. in the window that popup select new and add the path to your sdk. (for me "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk", yours might be diffrient). add path to platform-tools in same maner and comandline-tools. click ok to save and hopefully it will work.

Comment: English is not good. It lacks punctuation and there are some important typos. Please mark literals with "" (double quotes).