# React Native Cannot find supported Android SDK

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

My goal here is to learn how to debug in VSCode. After checking [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/debugging-react-native-vs-code/) the author mentions running `npx react-native doctor` to check your environment is set up for debugging

This question is similar to the [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797240/reactnative-cant-locate-android-sdk) however I have some different issues.

Firstly, I'm familiar with VSCode and do not want to use the android studio editor.
In regards to the problem it self. React-native is finding ANDROID_HOME and all the versions inside, however it doesn't like 31.0.0.

[image: Error after running npx react-native doctor]

Is 31.0.0 meant to be the same as .b31.0.0? If not I cannot see an obvious .b31.0.0 version..

[image: API Level 31 SDK Platforms]

Comment: hey  @Lauro235 , did you find the fix? Thanks