# Unable to accept sdk licenses on Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, licensing

I'm having problem accepting licenses for Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3. which comes up when run on Gitlab.

I've tried uninstalling Java 11 which is the latest jdk. But can't downgrade to Java 8. as per asked before here

[Failed to install android-sdk: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402772/failed-to-install-android-sdk-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-a)

./sdkmanager --licenses

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: use java 8 instead

Answer (score 0):

Please, check [this](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/10/24/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/) article on how to configure GitLab CI for Android projects.

The error you are seeing is because you are using an unsupported Java version. You should use Java 8. As you can see in the article, the base image used has Java 8 installed: `openjdk:8-jdk`.