# Error when trying to build dockerfile for Android project

Tags: android, docker

I am trying to build image for Android project for CI configuration (this will be the first step in my pipeline)

I am trying to run this command:

```
docker build -t android-build:some-name -f Dockerfile .
```

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7

ENV SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip" \
    ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk" \
    ANDROID_VERSION=29 \
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=28.0.3

RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
    && cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
    && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
    && unzip sdk.zip \
    && rm sdk.zip \
    && yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update

RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION}" \
    "platforms;android-${ANDROID_VERSION}" \
    "platform-tools"

RUN mkdir /application

WORKDIR /application
```

I am getting error as below:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
11:11:42
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
11:11:42
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
11:11:42
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
11:11:42
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:117)
11:11:42
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:93)
11:11:42
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
11:11:42
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
11:11:42
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) [0m [91m
11:11:42
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
11:11:42
    ... 5 more
11:11:42
  The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android     && cd "$ANDROID_HOME"     && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL     && unzip sdk.zip     && rm sdk.zip     && yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses' returned a non-zero code: 1
11:11:42
   [0m
```

I was trying also another configuration:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7

ENV SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6604631_latest.zip" \
    ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk" \
    ANDROID_VERSION=29 \
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=28.0.3 \

RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
    && cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
    && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
    && unzip sdk.zip \
    && rm sdk.zip

RUN yes | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --licenses

RUN $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --update

RUN yes | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME \
    "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION}" \
    "platforms;android-${ANDROID_VERSION}"

RUN mkdir /application

WORKDIR /application
```

But this gives me an error as below:

```
  Error response from daemon: failed to parse Dockerfile: Syntax error - can't find = in "RUN". Must be of the form: name=value
11:22:51
  Process exited with code 1
```

Unfortunately I am not a DevOps guy, so what is wrong with my configuration?
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have two option to fix this issue

- Downgrade JDK so you will have the required module for SDK as these are removed in `JDK 9+`
- Or use new SDK that does work with `JDK 9+`

```
FROM openjdk:8
ENV SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip" \
    ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk" \
    ANDROID_VERSION=29 \
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=28.0.3

RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
    && cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
    && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
    && unzip sdk.zip \
    && rm sdk.zip \
    && yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update

RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION}" \
    "platforms;android-${ANDROID_VERSION}" \
    "platform-tools"

RUN mkdir /application

WORKDIR /application
```

Or you can look into this for new SDK

> Google has been working on a new Android SDK Command-line Tools release that runs on current JVMs (9, 10, 11+) and does not depend on deprecated JAXB EE modules!

[SDK Tools for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652345/3288890)